# How to remove selected object from jquery

Tags: jquery

jquery 1.9.1 and i am submitting a form which has a single input on keypress event like this

```
//    when user clicks post quick reply
    $('.quickResponse').focus(function() {
        var quickResponse = $(this);
        if (quickResponse.val() === 'post quick response') {
            quickResponse.val('');
        }
        quickResponse.keypress(function(e) {
            if (e.keyCode === 13 && quickResponse.val() !== '') {
                post(quickResponse.parent());
                return false;
            }
        });
        quickResponse.blur(function() {
            if (quickResponse.val() === '') {
                quickResponse.val('post quick response');
                quickResponse.remove();
            }
        });
    });
```

html is like

```
                <form action="comment" method="post">
                    <input class="quickResponse" type="text" name="comment" value="post quick response"/>
                    <input type="hidden" name="itemId" value="${item.itemId}"/>
                    <input type="hidden" name="posterId" value="${item.customerId}"/>
                </form>
```

post for is just a function that submits the form via ajax and returns json which i update the page with.

Problem is if user focuses on the form blurs and refocuses again and again, the script continues to store all instances of the form and when user presses return key, all the form objects are submitted multiple times. How can I prevent this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you keep binding the other two events in the event handler.  Maybe it isn't the direct cause of the problem, but it is bad form.  Just bind them once instead.

```
var quickResponse = $('.quickResponse');

quickResponse.focus(function() {
    if (quickResponse.val() === 'post quick response') {
        quickResponse.val('');
    }
}).keypress(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 13 && quickResponse.val() !== '') {
        post(quickResponse.parent());
        return false;
    }
}).blur(function() {
    if (quickResponse.val() === '') {
        quickResponse.val('post quick response');
        quickResponse.remove();
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much it works, I guess I have to backtrack through my code and make corrections to some other places that I have been doing multiple unnecessary bindings.